# How to uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2010 Team Suit Beta 1 - ENU

Tags: uninstallation, visual-studio-2010

I installed "**Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2010 Team Suit Beta 1 - ENU**" from a CD received from Microsoft. Now, when I uninstall it, it stops at TFS Object Model (x86) component and ask for the CD with file **TFSObjectModel-x86_ENU.exe**. Since *I do not have CD* with me (I am away from home for couple of months), I cannot proceed with uninstalling. If I cancel the dialogbox, setup exists.

I want to remove this and install express edition of VS 2010.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running this uninstall utility 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4321

then uninstall TFSObjectModel first from add/remove programs. Then I was able to uninstall VS-2010.